# Laravel 5.1 - Hide section if variable has a value (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

i'm working with laravel 5.1 (ecommerce), i passed some variables to my view:

My variable "$price_coupon" con be "0" OR ">0" for example 10,20 etc...

I would like HIDE this:

```
<tr class="cart-subtotal" id="coupon">
<th>Coupon:</th>
<td>
<span class="amount">€{{ number_format($price_coupon, 2) }}</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

IF $price_coupon = 0 AND show IF $price_coupon > 0.

I think that this is feature for javascript right? how can do it? Thank you for your help!

This is all the table of my view:  order-detail.php

```
<table>
        <tbody>
           <tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th>Subtotale:</th>
                <td><span class="amount">€{{ number_format($total, 2) }}</span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="cart-subtotal" id="coupon">
                <th>Coupon:</th>
                <td><span class="amount">€{{ number_format($price_coupon, 2) }}</span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="shipping">
                <th>shipping:</th>
                <td>€<input type="text" id="price_ship" name="price_ship" class="price_ship" disabled /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="order-total">
                <th>Totale Ordine:</th>
                <td><strong><span class="amount">
                €<input type="text" id="total_ship" name="total_ship" class="total_ship" disabled />

              </span></strong> </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i corrected this question: I'm using also blade template.

Comment: `if(x ==0){...}` --- `if(x >0){...}`.

Comment: If this is in last step You should hide it directly in Blade.

Comment: How can i dot it with blade?

Answer (score 1):

in javascript ( jQuery )

```
 if( parseInt( $('.amount').text() ) <= 0 ){
      $('.amount').closest('tr').css('display', 'none');
 }else{
     $('.amount').closest('tr').css('display', '');
 }
```

You could also use

```
 parseFloat()
```

as it is currency and has decimal values.  But that would only matter for values like `0.4` or less because of rounding.

What's this weird thingy bob `€` pounds?  We just use `$` on my side of the pond.  Makes me wonder do they do this for jQuery `€('.class')` and this for php `€var;` hmm...

I actually have an English friend, to make a long story short he was back in the 'old' world visiting his family and said he got a 100 pound phone.  I said to him, wow that's heavy lol.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i fix this with blade, like this:

```
@if($price_coupon >0)
    <tr class="cart-subtotal">
        <th>Sconto:</th>
        <td><span class="amount">€{{ number_format($price_coupon, 2) }}</span></td>
    </tr>
@endif
```

Comment: You never mentioned you was using blade template system.